# Is it more efficient to have a table with one of its columns mostly empty or make a new table and refer to it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

Problem statement:
There are two different methods:1-use one table and waste a column or 2-use two tables.
[image]

Method 1: one table for all information (table1), but it has the column *role* that has only one value; all other rows are empty.

Method 2: Two tables one for rather unique information (table2) and another column has only one entry: the name of the table holding the rest of the values.

Summary: waste most of one column or create a new table, which one is more efficient?

Comment: Changed it into a proper picture once I got enough points! Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about **`Normalization`** of course it's much better to provide a way for removing ***redundant*** and ***null*** data.
you have this existing table:

```
    table1
----------------------------
role      | poster_id | name
varchar(n)| int       | varchar(n)
```

you can break above table into 2 **or even more** tables:

```
    table1              table2
------------------     ---------------------------
rol_id  | rol_name     rol_id   | poster_id | name
 tinyint| varchar(n)     tinyint| int       | varchar(n)
```

as **varchar(n)** takes spaces much more than **tinyint** and your main table is **table2** so the second scenario is more optimize.

**EDIT:**

if you have **only** one role and all users have only admin role (although this is not logic but possible) then of course for table2 (i.e:table_for_admin) it's better to have 2 columns(poster,name) and you already don't need to **table1**, maybe you meant to have a table per each role in this case you will not have redundant data and also you don't need to **table1** you can just name your tables as *ie: **table_for_admins**, **table_for_normalusers**, **table_for_powerusers*** but this is not good in case of ***Data Consistency.***

Comment: Isn't table 2 suppose to have only 2 columns: poster_id and name. We know that everyone is table 2 has on role.

Answer (score 1):

Neither!

Table 1 is your non-normalised table, the only additional information is if the poster is an admin so why not have a table with the `poster_id`s of the admins.

Having said that, don't the other users have roles too? Just `user` would be an adequate role name for normal posters.

Comment: Everyone else will be a user, wouldn't factoring this redundant information save space? That is my question.

Comment: Read this: [Wikipedia: Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: The role of `user` isn't redundant information, even if you aren't going to use it now. Having a blank field won't save any "space" as such; the entry still exists as an empty string.

Comment: If a user is always either an admin or a non-admin user, you can just change the 'role' column to an 'is_admin' column and it can be a tinyint which only takes up 1 byte per row. You'll get best of both worlds! Less storage and no JOIN bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the question: What role do the other users have? If they have no role in your application, they do not belong in the database. Clearly, they have a role; that role is "user" and it's reasonable to assign that role explicitly in the database.

Do you envision that a user might have more than one role in the future? If so, you may want to implement this pattern (taken from [Data Modeling: A Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071623981)):

[image]

Here you have three tables, the minimum required to implement a many-to-many relationship. The middle table is called a junction or linking table; you can include date attributes there or not, depending on whether you care about storing a historical record. Any information that depends only on the role goes in the table on the right; any information that depends only on the user goes in the table on the left.

If you leave off the date attributes, the junction table only stores the primary keys from the other two tables, and each user, role, and all their corresponding information are stored only once. This is a standard way to implement roles in the relational model.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this is with a [junction table](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Junction_Tables_%28Many-to-Many_Relationships%29). So the answer to your question is that neither of your proposals are the most efficient way to structure your database, you need *3* tables.

[image]

This will really help you out in the long run when you need to add new tables/columns because the roles will be in an independent table.

Comment: The junction table is only necessary if users can have multiple roles (i.e., a many-to-many relationship). In the case of a one-to-one relationship, either one or two tables could also be correct, depending on the nature of the roles. But it's true that using three tables in this case is more flexible.